# Xcode : Change WebView Url on tableview item click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I got a static tableList of Categories on a view controller (called CategoriesViewController ) in main storyboard, this contain the categories of the Blog shown in a webView in fistViewController.

When I click (or tap) in a Category it must to send me to webView Page and change the URL (eg mainpage is www.example.com and category is www.example.com/category)

I've just made a simple webView in first page view like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.example.com";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

How can I interact with elements in another controller and change `NSURLRequest` appending the category after slash?

Should I get the elements on the Table View as ID?

And what's the code to archieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood that is a TableView. So you need to implement the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and I believe you have an array of those categories. so you need to get the `indexPath.row` (`indexPath` is an argument in this method) and pass it along to the next view controller by appending it to the initial URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you provide a code example? I'm just a noob in Objective-C

Comment: The categories name isn't in an Array, these are hard coded in an static table

Comment: is it a table view? you can find the code samples. just google those things i wrote. and why don't you use swift? it's much easier to learn if you are new to ios development. 
1. check what is table view and it's delegate methods (one of which is didSelectRowAtIndexPath) 2. find how to pass the value to next view controller

Comment: Thanks for the replies I think I'll switch my project to swift, was using obj-c cause of the large amount of guides and tutorials on the web.

Comment: i would suggest using swift cuz it's newer and all the tutorials (recent ones) are all in swift. all those obj c are 2-3 or more years old :)